# Javascript Reduce Challenge, Getting the value of an Obj's Key

Tags: javascript

I'm following a course online and one of the challenges is this:

**Write a function called extractKey which accepts two parameters, an array of objects, and the name of a key and returns an array with just the values for that key: You must use reduce.**

```
extractKey([{name: "Elie", isInstructor:true},{name: "Tim", isInstructor:true},{name: "Matt", isInstructor:true}], "name");

// ["Elie", "Tim", "Matt"]
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
function extractKey(arr, key) {
  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    console.log(a.push(b[key]))
  }, [])
}
```

But its returning 1. I have a general idea of pushing each value into the empty array, but when console logging each value, a will return undefined at the next accumulator.

Comment: Why `reduce`, not `map`? Also note that, in your current implementation, neither `extractKey` nor the reduce function actually return anything.

Comment: The function isn't returning anything, and you're printing the return value of the `.push()` method, not the array's contents.

Comment: The challenge is to use reduce. I've already done it with map. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use reduce then I'd combine it with concat like this.

```js
var arr = [{
  name: "Elie",
  isInstructor: true
}, {
  name: "Tim",
  isInstructor: true
}, {
  name: "Matt",
  isInstructor: true
}]

function extractKeys(array, key) {
  return array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    return acc.concat(obj[key])
  }, [])
}

console.log(extractKeys(arr, 'name'))
```

Comment: i thought the same (and deleted it).

Answer (score 0):

If you use reduce (not really neccessary here), you need to pass on the accumulator:

```
 function extractKey(arr, key) {
    arr.reduce(function(acc, el) {
      console.log(a.push(el[key]))
      return acc; // <--
    }, [])
 }
```

Alternatively a good old for loop might be easier to understand:

```
  function extractKey(arr, key){
    const result = [];  
    for(const el of arr)
      result.push(el[key]);     
    return result;
 }
```

Finally you also might use *map* instead and currying to beautify it:

```
  const extract = key => obj => obj[key];

  const result = original.map(extract("name"));
```

Comment: `console.log(push ...)`? what for?

Answer (score 0):

you were very close but with reduce you have to return the value after every iteration of your callback since only the accumulator's value is saved

```
function extractKey(arr, key) {
  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    a.push(b[key])
    console.log(a)
    return a;
  }, []);
}
```